# Клиент - сервер - офис

Tags: delphi, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте!) Нужно реализовать связь клиента с офисом. Клиент открывает программу, вводит свои данные, нажимает отправить. В офисе открывают программу и туда приходит сообщение, с данными клиента. Как я понял, нужно реализовать связь клиентской программы с сервером, т.е  отправляется запрос с данными (отправка через Интернет), затем в офисе программа синхронизируется с сервером и получает эти данные... Как это реализовать? Как реализовать работу сервера? Что для этого надо? Как связаться с ним? Есть какие-нибудь подсказки, или советы?.. Среда для разработки - DELPHI...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если делфи, то ключевые слова будут - **TClientSocket** и **TServerSocket** (в случае delphi 7+ это могут быть **TTcpServer** и **TTcpClient**). Клиенты с 2-мя типами запросов ("клиент", который отправляет данные и "офис", который читает с сервера) и непосредственно сам сервер, на котором хранилище данных. Работать будет примерно так: сначала открытие сокета - начало ожидания соединения клиентов; подключение клиента и обмен данными - сервер определяет тип запроса ("офис" или "клиент") и соответственно обрабатывает; затем отключение клиента и закрытие его соединения с сервером.

Comment: Извините за вопрос, но как реализовать "сервер"? Т.е нужно покупать или можно как-то без него обойтись? Отправка идет через Интернет, как это реализовать, или все описано в работах с TClientSocket и TServerSocket?...

Comment: Всё есть в описаниях TClientSocket и TServerSocket. Сервер используйте локальный, т.е. клиенту нужно будет подключаться к 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

Comment: Извините, но нужно чтобы отправка шла через интернет... т.е сервер и клиенты удалены друг от друга...

Comment: Какая разница. Сделайте, чтобы программа работала локально, а задеплоить куда-нибудь сервер и поменять одну строчку (адрес) всегда можно успеть

Comment: Ну для начала я так и думал сделать, но все таки как это реализовать не подскажите?)

Comment: Это лучше поискать, например, по ключевым словам storage service. Обычно можно задеплоить своё приложение, но бесплатно будут ограниченные возможности. Например, дневное ограничение вызовов, кол-во вызовов в минуту, размер хранилища, процессорное время хранилища и т.д. и т.п. Вот популярный http://aws.amazon.com/, но нужно читать условия. Хотя если это учебное задание, то это всё вряд ли понадобиться.

Comment: Оно не учебное) Ну как бы, на нем я научусь как делать;)а так его хотят использовать в реальных целях для связи клиентов с сервером)

Comment: Тогда для этого лучше создать отдельный вопрос про выбор storage service.

Comment: ОК) Благодарю за оказанную помощь;)

Comment: А тут офисная программа будет сервером, будет принимать данные, и их сохранять в БД, привязанную к этой программе...

Answer (score 0):

Когда я занимался еще 6-й студией, там был winSocks)

Comment: Можно по-подробнее, что это?)

Answer (score 0):

А что именно вы хотите делать? Если вы хотите сделать простой клиент и простой сервер, самым оптимальным для вас будет обмениваться информацией через обычные TCPIP сокеты.

Comment: В клиентской программе, пользователь заполняет поля определенными данными, и затем отправляет их в офис... Я впервые с этим сталкиваюсь, поэтому даже не знаю с чего начать...

Comment: Советую почитать про сокеты http://hashcode.ru/questions/1608/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-winsock2-h тут правда про С++, а также про сериализацию\десериализацию данных.

Answer (score 0):

Да, в принципе ваш вопрос ясен. Имеется в виду, что ПК типа офисного должен принять от людей данные. Возможно и не от одних. Т.е. чел. приходит на работу и включает ПК. В нерабочее время, естественно сервер существовать не может. А что вам мешает его вообще не выключать? Тока питание иметь бесперебойное. Это и есть сервер как таковой.Плюсы-контроль 100%,изменение ПО причём любого,а главное максимальная секретность ваших данных. Открытость никогда не была без внимания. Пусть даже данные ничего такого не несут. Но нехорошие люди могут из одного цента сделать миллион и это факт.

Comment: Ответ, увы, не по существу. Из условий всё очень похоже на обычную почту. Интерфейс для Windows - mapi. Какие control'ы в Delphi для mapi - не знаю, но думаю, что должны быть. 
В крайнем случае - добавляются.
Клиентская программа кодирует почтовое сообщение и отправляет на почтовый сервер. Программа в офисе получает письмо, преобразует текст/вложение и работает со своим пользователем.

Comment: Не по существу? А вопрос был как раз про сервер! Какую он будет прогу использовать-дело хозяйское. Да требуемая функциональность более похожа на почту. Но простой почтовый сервер не запрограммирован на некий "транспортный буфер"! Он только может скинуть уведомление. А писалось, о приоритетах в защите информации. Не как отписка, а как общее правило.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вы занимаетесь бесполезными вещами, то что вы сейчас описали пишется на php.
Во первых в виде приложения это будет не удобно во вторых если ваш клиент работает не под Windows вы автоматически теряете клиента в третьих не надо городить там где это не нужно.
То что вы описали очень похоже на систему запросов (тикетов). Такие системы уже есть и достаточно высокие по качеству в том числе и бесплатные.

Если сильно приспичило на Delphi то там вроде был компонент Web-Server, формируйте  на нем странички и обрабатывайте запросы от веб-браузера, как минимум проблема с клиентом отпадет.

Comment: Я конечно понимаю здесь все оч "умные" люди собрались!) Но мне сказали, что надо сделать, я и делаю) Спасибо конечно про web-server) И отдельное спасибо за "то что вы сейчас описали пишется на php";)как нибудь обязательно попробую)

Comment: По вопросу совершенно не понятно что за программа, я предложил самое эффективное решение из того что понял.

Comment: Спасибо, wint1000;) Делаю как могу, к работе отношусь серьезно, тем более впервые с таким связываюсь) Если в дальнейшем нужно будет сопровождение и работа над версиями выше, то уже надо будет по другому смотреть) С++ эт штука, но так "хорошо", как с Делфи я не знаком, так поверхностно, но есть к чему стремиться;)Спасибо;)

Comment: @wint1000 Правильно или добавлять комментарий, или обновлять свой предыдущий ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Самый легкий вариант - поставить в офисе сервер базы данных (если делфи, то Interbase или Firebird).

> Клиент открывает программу, вводит свои данные, нажимает отправить.

И все записыватся в базу.

> В офисе открывают программу и туда приходит сообщение с данными клиента.

Т.е. читает последние добавления в базу (ну, или как понадобится).