# Как разделить данные, получаемые от клиента?

Tags: delphi, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте!) Начал потихоньку разбираться с реализацией поставленной [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1724/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81.) задачи, но возникает куча вопросов) Как разделить данные получаемые от клиента? К примеру, сейчас данные на клиентской программе вводятся в разные Edit и отправляются. На офисной программе все пишется в Memo сплошным текстом. В дальнейшем нужно, чтобы эти данные заносились в те же Edit, но в офисной программе (сервер), или даже в ячейки таблицы БД.
Программа "Клиент":

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ClientSocket1.Address:='127.0.0.1';
ClientSocket1.Port:=1025;
ClientSocket1.Active := True;
end;   

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ClientSocket1.Active:=false;
ClientSocket1.Close;
close;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(name.text+family.Text+email.text);
name.Text:='';
family.Text:='';
email.Text:='';
end;
```

Программа "Сервер":

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Close;
end;    

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  ServerSocket1.Port:=1025;
  Memo1.Lines.Insert(0,'Server starting');
  ServerSocket1.Open;
  ServerSocket1.Active:=True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ServerSocket1.Active := False;
Memo1.Lines.Insert(0,'Server stopped');
ServerSocket1.Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
Memo1.Lines.Insert(0,'Клиент '+InTtoStr(Socket.SocketHandle)+' подсоединился');
end;    

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
Memo1.Lines.Insert(0,'Клиент '+InTtoStr(Socket.SocketHandle)+' отсоединился');
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var ClientText: String;
    i: Integer;
begin
ClientText:= InTtoStr(Socket.SocketHandle) + '>' + Socket.ReceiveText;
Memo1.Lines.Insert(0,ClientText);
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
  var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
Memo1.Lines.Insert(0,'Ошибка клиента. Код = '+IntToStr(ErrorCode));
end;
```

Comment: Всё это полнейшее безобразие, какое ещё поискать. Скидка только на то, что это учебный пример. 

Comment: Извините, а почему?)

Comment: Здесь все плохо. Полная каша. Обработка низкоуровнего сетевого протокола, работа с сокетами, управление предсталением.. и все это на бедной несчастнгй форме. А обработчики нажатий кнопок напрямую обращаются к сокету. В общем, полный набор антипаттернов. Уж простите меня.

Comment: Да вы что??... Если бы вы прочли предыдущий вопрос по этим меткам, то вы бы поняли, что я впервые с этим сталкиваюсь... Если вы знаток в 
этом деле, так приведите свой пример решения проблемы, и объясните что к чему...

Comment: Почитайте книжки про паттерны и архитертуру проекта :)

Comment: Какие именно? посоветуйте... хотя вопрос не в этом заключался...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для такого простого случая можно просто вставлять символ разделителя. А при десериализации воспользоваться функцией, которая появилась в Delphi 2010:

```
SplitString(const S, Delimiters: string): TStringDynArray;
```

(в StrUtils.pas).
Она получает на вход строку и знак разделителя, а возвращает массив строк после разделения входной строки. Если пользуетесь более ранней версией, то можете попробовать такой пример:

```
uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils;

procedure Split(Delimiter: Char; Str: string; ListOfStrings: TStrings) ;
begin
   ListOfStrings.Clear;
   ListOfStrings.Delimiter     := Delimiter;
   ListOfStrings.DelimitedText := Str;
end;

var
   OutPutList: TStringList;
begin
   OutPutList := TStringList.Create;
   try
     Split('$', 'param1=value1$param2=value2$param3=value3', OutPutList) ;
     Writeln(OutPutList.Text);
     Readln;
   finally
     OutPutList.Free;
   end;
end.
```

Comment: ага понятно) т.е я отправляю сообщение ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(name.text+'&'+family.Text+'&'+email.text), затем textMsg:=Socket.ReceiveText, далее пишу Split('$', 'textMsg', OutPutList); и в цикле по длине массива-строк обрабатываю эти сроки, так?)

Comment: В массиве будет три элемента - это ваши три параметра = {name.text, family.text, email.text}. Дальше с ними делайте, что угодно, вывод в Memo, в консоль, и т.д. Попробуйте запустить эту программу в виде консольного приложения (т.е. скопируйте, как есть), и попробуйте поредактировать текст программы.

Comment: Хорошо, тока консоли нет) Я проработаю ваш ответ в своем приложение) Если возникнут трудности я вам напишу, если конечно можно) Да и еще, извините конечно, куда писать то?) Спасибо)

Comment: Что значит нет консоли? Возможность создания консольного приложения есть во всех средах разработки (Delphi, Kylix). Это быстрый и удобный способ проверки работы небольших кусков кода. Пишите, конечно. Здесь на форуме обсудим.

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался с консолью) Все работает) программа вывела такой ответ 
param1=value1 
param2=value2 
param3=value3 
т.е получается OutPutList.text[0]='param1=value1' и т.д)

Comment: мне кажется, или если ввести в family ан&т&он, будет бардак и фейл?

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае то, что вас интересует - это механизм оборачивания структурированных данных, называется **сериализация** и **десериализация**. Допустим, у вас есть некоторых внутренний формат. Сериализация - процесс заворачивания данных из приложения в этот формат. Потом данные в вашем формате передаются по сети, затем часть приложения, принявшая эти данные, выполняет десериализацию, то есть читает данные из вашего формата. Внутренний формат - это полностью ваш выбор: либо можете воспользоваться готовым форматом (типа XML или другой формат, для любого языка существует множество библиотек с парсерами различных форматов), либо придумать свой формат. Приведу очень упрощенный пример. Допустим вы хотите передавать в запросе три строковых параметра, для такой цели, конечно, излишне прикреплять парсеры и прочее. Так, форматом может быть что угодно. Если вы точно знаете, что какой-то символ не будет встречаться в тексте, вы можете его использовать как разделитель при передаче по сети. Например, значок доллара. Т.е. паттерн будет выглядеть так:

```
 (.*)$(.*)$(.*)
```

Либо параметры могут передаваться в произвольном порядке и/или какой-либо из них может отсутствовать. Тогда уместно воспользоваться форматом подобным этому:

```
 param_name_1=value1$param_name_2=value2$param_name_3=value3
```

и предусмотреть, что могут приходить и такие данные

```
param_name_3=value3$param_name_2=value2$param_name_1=value1
```

или

```
param_name_2=value2$param_name_1=value1
```

Если у вас строки могут содержать любой символ - это тоже не беда, хоть и усложняет задачу (придется реализовать свой механизм экранирования). Для того чтобы написать собственный простой случай механизма сериализации и десериализации достаточно прочитать про **регулярные выражения** (проверка строк на соответствие шаблону) в языке программирования, на котором вы пишете, в данном случае это delphi. Значит, вам нужна библиотека **[TRegExpr](http://regexpstudio.com/Downloads/regexpr_RU.rar)**. Для её использования не нужны никакие DLL. В качестве языка правил используется подмножество регулярных выражений Перла - это к тому, что в при поиске правил составления шаблона вы можете искать правила для языка Перл (хотя к библиотеке есть большой хелп на русском языке).

Comment: а не слишком сложно для такой простой вещи? по сути, ты написал то же, что и я, но, при этом, добавил сериализацию, которая здесь ни к чему вовсе

Comment: Я добавил её к тому, что сейчас он только начинает писать своё приложение и это не учебное задание, а значит, что позже может понадобиться "универсальный" механизм передачи данных, а не шаблон для трёх строковых параметров. Сериализация - ключевое слово, по которому можно сразу найти желаемую информацию. И, кстати, даже заворачивание трех параметров по шаблону - всё равно является сериализацией.

Comment: Просто все встроенные алгоритмы сериализации предназначены для передачи любых(!) данных. Искать особо нечего, код даже по моему краткому посту написать несложно, сейчас добавлю). Только "универсальный" механизм обычно далеко не лучший, т.к. медленный.

Comment: про медленный ты прав. только это никак не доказывает избыточности моего ответа :)

Comment: Ничего лишнего в ответе нет.

Answer (score -1):

вставляй разделители между name.text, family.Text и email.text. сами их проверяй на наличие выбранного разделителя, и удаляй.

Comment: То есть анализ строки проводить каждый раз?!) Можно пример кода? Спасибо)

Comment: Это мысль в правильном направлении ;)